# Convexity proof of $h$ function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, convex-analysis

Let $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Assume that $h'(0)$ exists and is bigger than $1$. Moreover, $h(0) \geq 0$. Show that $h(x) > x$ for $x > 0$.

I tried using monotonicity of slopes of convex function but I am not sure if this is correct and not sure about this info about derivative.

Comment: If are not sure if your proof is correct then you should show it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $0<y<x$. Then $y=tx+(1-t)0$ where $t=\frac  y  x$. So $h(y) \leq th(x)+(1-t)h(0)$. I will let you show using this and some simple algebra that $\frac {h(x)-h(0)} {x-0} \geq  \frac {h(y)-h(0)} {y-0}$. Letting $y \to 0+$ we get $\frac {h(x)-h(0)} {x-0}\geq h'(0)>1$. Hence, $h(x)> h(0)+x\ge x$

Comment: Thank you very much! It's exactly the way I have done it.